# How do I merge two results of an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to merge results of two sql queries as one

query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(class) as show, year
FROM lee
where class = 'Show'
GROUP BY year
```

Result

```
show         year
185          2016
296          2020
655          2019
```

Query 2

```
SELECT COUNT(class) as movie, year
FROM lee
where class = 'movie'
GROUP BY year
```

Result

```
   movie           year
    556          2016
    987          2020
    690          2019
```

How do I achieve something like this:

```
        movie          show           year
        556            185           2016
        987            296           2020
        690            655           2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'show' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as show,
       SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'movie' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as movie,
       year
FROM lee
GROUP BY year;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case when` statement for choosing class for counting.

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN class = 'movie' THEN 1 END) as movie,
       count(CASE WHEN class = 'show' THEN 1 END) as show,
       year
FROM lee
GROUP BY year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine solution is not the most beautiful but it's for give an other option

```
SELECT m.movie, s.show, m.YEAR FROM
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS movie, YEAR FROM LEE WHERE CLASS = 'movie' GROUP BY YEAR) m
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS show, YEAR FROM LEE WHERE CLASS = 'show' GROUP BY YEAR) s 
ON (s.YEAR = m.YEAR);
```